# how to add a different model form to modelformset_factory

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

With respect to these models:

```
class Projects(models.Model):
    projectDescription = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null = True,)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices = Status_CHOICES, default = 4)
    projectOwner = models.ForeignKey(staff, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null = True,)

class Updates(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Projects, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    update = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null = True,)
    updateDate = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now, editable = False)
    addedBy = models.CharField(max_length=35,blank=True,)
```

I want to create a view that displays forms for all of the current *projects*. This is easy using a `modelformset_factory`. But how can I also add an additional form to each of these project form instances so that an *Update* to the project (foreign key) can be made?
Ideally the user makes changes to various projects, adds an update to one or several projects, then submits the form to save all the changes.
What I have below seems to be very close, but it is saving an update to each project with the value of whatever I typed into the last form. Which seems to be because the form is not unique. I went down the road of using prefix's which didn't seem to get me anywhere either. help!

**update form**

```
class updateForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(updateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    class Meta:
        model = Updates
        fields = ('update',)
```

**view:**

```
def MDSprojects(request):
    projects = Projects.objects.filter(dept = 'Assistive Technology')
    projectFormset = modelformset_factory(Projects, form=EditProjectForm, extra = 0)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formsetA = projectFormset(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if formsetA.is_valid():
            for f in formsetA:
                formA = f.save(commit = False)
                id = formA.id
                formA.save()
                formsetB = updateForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
                if formsetB.is_valid():
                    formB = formsetB.save(commit = False)
                    project = Projects.objects.get(id = id)
                    formB.project = project
                    formB.save()
                else:
                    print(formsetB.errors)
            return redirect('MDS_Projects')
        else:
            print(formsetA.errors)
    else:
        formsetA = projectFormset(queryset = projects)
        formsetB = updateForm()
        return render(request,'MDSprojectsB.html',{'formset':formsetA,'formsetB':formsetB,})
```

**Template:**

```
<form method="POST" enctype= multipart/form-data>
  {{ formset.management_form }}
  {% csrf_token %}
  {%for form in formset%}
    {{ form.management_form }}
    {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
      {{ hidden }}
    {% endfor %}
  <div class="card border-primary mb-3" style="max-width: 85rem;">
    <div class="card-header text-primary">
       <strong>{{form.instance.projectDescription}}</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body text-primary"> Project Name: {{form.projectDescription}}</div>
    <div class="card-body text-primary"> Status: {{form.status}}</div>
    <div class="card-body text-primary"> Status: {{form.projectOwner}}</div>
    <div class="card-body text-primary"> Status: {{form.priority}}</div>
    <div>
        {{ formsetB.management_form }}
        {% for hidden in formsetB.hidden_fields %}
          {{ hidden }}
        {% endfor %}
        {{formsetB}}
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
  <button class="btn btn-success btn" type="submit">Save Changes</button>
 </form>
```

**EDIT:**

Perhaps another way of explaining my question is:

If I had the same models as above:

```
class Projects(models.Model):
    projectDescription = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null = True,)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices = Status_CHOICES, default = 4)
    projectOwner = models.ForeignKey(staff, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null = True,)

class Updates(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Projects, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    update = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null = True,)
    updateDate = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now, editable = False)
    addedBy = models.CharField(max_length=35,blank=True,)
```

I want to have a view that renders all of the current projects as individual forms so that the user can make changes to the project model in one view. Additionally I want the user to be able to add an update to each project as well.

So for example, if I had 3 projects, I would expect to see 3 forms on the page. Each form would contain the fields to modify this project (so these form fields would be pre-populated with the current values). Then lastly (the part I'm stuck on) would be an additional empty field to add an update to the project.

Comment: If you have 2 projects, projectA; projectB and these project have the updates A1, A2, A3, B1, B2. Do you want to show form for Project A followed by updates forms for A1, A2, A3 and form for Project B followed by updates forms for B1, B2. I did not get your aimed result.

Comment: Hi @ismail Taha AYKAC, I added some additional clarification in my question. I want to see a form for each project, and on the same form I want an empty input field to add an update to the project. So the project form would be to edit, and the update form field would be to add. Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Solution I

What you have done is almost correct. You have initiated an UpdateForm but you treated it as if it was a formset. However it's a Form instance. If you alter your code as below you may achieve your goal.

models.py

```py
class Project(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=4)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(staff, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    ...

class Update(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)
    added_by = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True)
```

forms.py

```py
class CreateUpdateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Update
        fields = ('notes')


class EditProjectForm(ModelForm)
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('__all__')
```

views.py

```py
def mds_projects(request):
    project_formset = modelformset_factory(Project, form=EditProjectForm, extra=0)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = project_formset(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid():
            for f in formset:
                project = f.save(commit = False)

                update_form = CreateUpdateForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
                if update_form.is_valid():
                    update = update_form.save(commit = False)
                    update.project = project
                    project.save()
                    update.save()
                else:
                    print(update_form.errors)
            return redirect('MDS_Projects')
        else:
            print(formset.errors)
    else:
        projects = Project.objects.filter(dept='Assistive Technology')
        formset = project_formset(queryset=projects)
        update_form = updateForm()
        return render(request,'MDSprojectsB.html',{'formset':formset, 'update_form':update_form})
```

MDSprojectsB.html

```html
<form method="POST" enctype= multipart/form-data>
  {{ formset.management_form }}
  {% csrf_token %}
  {%for form in formset%}
    {{ form.management_form }}
    {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
      {{ hidden }}
    {% endfor %}
  <div class="card border-primary mb-3" style="max-width: 85rem;">
    <div class="card-header text-primary">
       <strong>{{form.instance.description}}</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body text-primary"> Project Name: {{form.description}}</div>
    <div class="card-body text-primary"> Status: {{form.status}}</div>
    <div class="card-body text-primary"> Owner: {{form.owner}}</div>
    <div class="card-body text-primary"> Priority: {{form.priority}}</div>
    <div>
        {{ update_form }}
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
  <button class="btn btn-success btn" type="submit">Save Changes</button>
 </form>
```

---

## Solution II

You can also use one form for both models. Since you only want update notes for the `Update` model you can add additional form field to update project form thus you would not need an additional update form.

forms.py

```py
class EditProjectForm(ModelForm)
    update_notes = forms.CharField(max_length=50, help_text='50 characters max.')
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('__all__')
```

views.py

```py
def mds_projects(request):
    project_formset = modelformset_factory(Project, form=EditProjectForm, extra=0)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = project_formset(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid():
            for f in formset:
                project = f.save(commit = False)
                update = Update.objects.create(notes=f.cleaned_data['update_notes'], project=project)
                project.save()

            return redirect('MDS_Projects')
        else:
            print(formset.errors)
    else:
        projects = Project.objects.filter(dept='Assistive Technology')
        formset = project_formset(queryset=projects)
        return render(request,'MDSprojectsB.html',{'formset':formset})
```

MDSprojectsB.html

```html
<form method="POST" enctype= multipart/form-data>
  {{ formset.management_form }}
  {% csrf_token %}
  {%for form in formset%}
    {{ form.management_form }}
    {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
      {{ hidden }}
    {% endfor %}
  <div class="card border-primary mb-3" style="max-width: 85rem;">
    <div class="card-header text-primary">
       <strong>{{form.instance.description}}</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body text-primary"> Project Name: {{form.description}}</div>
    <div class="card-body text-primary"> Status: {{form.status}}</div>
    <div class="card-body text-primary"> Owner: {{form.owner}}</div>
    <div class="card-body text-primary"> Priority: {{form.priority}}</div>
    <div class="card-body text-primary"> Update: {{form.update_notes}}</div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
  <button class="btn btn-success btn" type="submit">Save Changes</button>
 </form>
```

---

P.S. The code you provided has some violation of both python and django naming conventions. Please try to follow these conventions. I have fixed some of those in my code. For example, you should not name your models plural, you should use camelCase naming for functions and variables.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much for taking the time to help me. I ended up using solution 2, as it is less code and seems cleaner to me. Any reason why this was solution 2 and not 1? Also, I had to make 2 small changes. I made the update_notes field not requires, as it was throwing an error, and I also made an if statement to handle the event update_notes were left empty, otherwise even the empty fields would save. Otherwise worked perfectly. Thanks again

Comment: Since it’s more similar to your solution, I gave the order as this way. I would have prefered the solution 2. I am glad it worked out 